# Launch remote assistance request?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, remote-assistance

I'd like to make a button or link that launches a remote assistance request to a designated computer. Is it possible to just do this through the command line? If not I'll use vb.net. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im researching a similar thing and found the following :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a2f8a3d5-e3f7-4d21-a611-0a0725f3df73

Hope this helps a little,

Stu

Comment: Useful if you always know the PC name of the computer you're offering help to. More research found that theres no way to request help from a certain PC.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is similar to the accepted answer, but I thought I could elaborate further.  If you want the user/client to request a Remote Assistance session, you might want to look more into the msra.exe command.

For example, a call such as `msra.exe /email [password]` would open create a ticket and attach it to an email for the user to send to someone.  As far as I know, you can't automatically populate the email address it gets sent to, but it still could be a workable solution.

This technet article explains some of the options:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff356868.aspx